# Permissions not appearing when using ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to get permission from the user to access their location. I have asked for permission in the Android Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication2"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

When using ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.) I can't seem to access ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION using Manifest.permission. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
  import androidx.core.location.LocationListenerCompat;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.location.Location;
  import android.location.LocationListener;
  import android.location.LocationManager;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
        this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
                Log.i("Location", location.toString());
            }
        };

//error is here
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your imports of MainActivity class

Comment: I have added my imports

Comment: This is missing in your imports import android.Manifest or complete the statement where you have left, you will definitely get hint to add import